# random.choice valores con coma para set_windows_size

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Lo que quiero realizar es que el valor de set_window_size se establezca de manera aleatoria con una lista definida pero no puedo lo que tengo entendido que debe ser por las comas. 
¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

```py
import pytest
import time     
import json 
import random      
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
resolucion_pantalla_navegador_lista = ('1024,768', '800,600', '1366, 728')
resolucion_navegador = driver.set_window_size( (random.choice(resolucion_pantalla_navegador_lista) ) )
resolucion_navegador
#driver.set_window_size(1366, 728) NOTA: cambiar a resoluciones aleatorias
driver.get("https://www.sitioweb.com.ar/")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que el metodo *set_window_size* espera dos numeros enteros (x,y) y le estás pasando una cadena de texto con los números.

Cambia las cadenas por tuplas y prueba otra vez.
Ejemplo:

```
resolucion_pantalla_navegador_lista = ( (1024,768),(800,600),(1366,728) )

....

resolucion_navegador = driver.set_window_size( *random.choice(resolucion_pantalla_navegador_lista) )
```

El "*" antes de random es para indicarle a la funcion que lo que queremos son los elementos de la tupla por separado, y no el elemento de la tupla entera.

Por ejemplo:

```
In [1]: tupla = ((1,2),(3,4))

In [2]: def suma(a,b):
   ...:     return a + b
   ...:

In [3]: suma(tupla[0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-48553d26bb0b> in <module>
----> 1 suma(tupla[0])

TypeError: suma() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

In [4]: suma(*tupla[0])
Out[4]: 3
```

Verás que si no uso el asterisco en realidad lo que estoy haciendo es llamar a la funcion suma de esta forma:

```
suma(a=(1,2),b=vacio)
```

Y con el asterisco sería tal que así:

```
suma(a=1,b=2)
```

...porque el asterisco desempaqueta el contenido de la tupla (o de una lista, dict...etc) en el mismo orden tanto de la tupla como de los argumentos de la función.

Espero que te lo haya aclarado

Comment: Como andas jose, muchas gracias por contestar.

driver.set_window_size(resolucion_pantalla_navegador_lista)
TypeError: set_window_size() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'

Tambien he probado asi: resolucion_pantalla_navegador_lista = random.choice( ['1024, 768', '800, 600', '1366, 768'] )

Comment: Perdona, se me olvidó el asterisco para desempaquetar la tupla en lugar de pasar el elemento entero como unico, por eso se queja de que le falta un argumento (_missing 1 required positional argument_) He corregido el código

Comment: Si, inclusive lo he realizado como lo realizaste. Lo que desconocia era lo de el asterisco. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: El truco del almendruco :) Según vayas cogiendo experiencia y sintiéndote cómodo con Python verás que hay formas de resolver problemas que son más sencillas y _pythonicas_